# How to create multiple XMPP clients in nodejs using websockets

Tags: websocket, xmpp

I have an electron app that creates a websocket connection to a node js server. It sends a JSON request to that server telling it to create a xmpp client.

```
let message = {
  action: "setupXmpp",
  data: {
    username,
    password,
  },
};

socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

Within that server I have a switch that reads the message action and creates the xmpp client. The code in xmppActions is standard boilerplate taken from xmpp's [repo](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/tree/master/packages/client)

```
const xmppActions = require("./Webapp/xmppActions");
case "setupXmpp":
    console.log(`Received setupXmpp request`);

    var { username, password } = message.data;
    const xmpp = xmppActions.setUpXMPPconn(username, password);

    xmpp.on("online", async (address) => {
      console.log("▶", "online as", address.toString());
      ws.send("Register xmpp Success!");
    });
    break;
```

Everything works fine I can create an xmpp client and send messages, all good.

My issue is when i have two clients open and they both register (with different username and password ) whoever is the last request always overrides the previous register. I've done a wireshark trace and the two websocket connections are created as I would expect but when it comes to sending messages they both use the most recent register. I assume it's because the XMPP client is a constant and whoever is last it uses those for all future requests.

How do I make it so that each websocket connection gets its own XMPP client almost like a request scoped client specific for each websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a constant outside the websocket connection, changed it to have a var inside so each connection had it own client.